# Stable Diffusion pipe always outputs 512*512 images regardless of the input resolution

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, stable-diffusion

I'm making an inpainting app and I'm almost getting the desired result except the pipeline object outputs a 512*512 image no matter what resolution I pass in. I'm running this on the CPU, it's the onnx-converted, AMD-friendly version of stable diffusion.

Here's the code I think is relevant:

```
class CustomDiffuser:
    def __init__(self, provider:Literal['CPUExecutionProvider', 'DmlExecutionProvider']='CPUExecutionProvider'):

        self.pipe_text2image = None
        self.pipe_inpaint = None
        self.image = None
        self.sam = None
        self.provider = provider


    def load_model_for_inpainting(
            self, 
            path: str = '../stable_diffusion_onnx_inpainting', 
            safety_checker=None
    ):
        self.pipe_inpaint = OnnxStableDiffusionInpaintPipeline.from_pretrained(path, provider=self.provider, revision='onnx', safety_checker=safety_checker)        


    def inpaint_with_prompt(
            self, 
            image: cv2.typing.MatLike | Image.Image, 
            mask: cv2.typing.MatLike | Image.Image,
            height: int, 
            width: int,             
            prompt: str = '', 
            negative: str = '',
            steps: int = 10, 
            cfg: float =  7.5,
            noise: float = 0.75
    ):

        pipe = self.pipe_inpaint

        image = image.resize((width, height))
        mask = mask.resize((width, height))

        output_image = pipe(
            prompt,
            image,
            mask,
            #strength=noise,
            guidance_scale=cfg
        )

        return output_image

  
diffuser = CustomDiffuser('CPUExecutionProvider')
    
diffuser.load_model_for_inpainting('C:/path/to/repository/stable_diffusion_onnx_inpainting')

output = diffuser.inpaint_with_prompt(
    Image.open(image_path),
    Image.fromarray(headless_selfie_mask.astype(np.uint8)),
    576, #height first 
    384,                
    'a picture of a man dressed in a darth vader costume, full body shot, front view, light saber',
    ''
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the height and width as follows:

```py
output_image = pipe(
    prompt,
    image,
    mask,
    height,
    width,
    #strength=noise,
    guidance_scale=cfg
)
```

If you check the source code - the [height](https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/blob/f0c81562a43c183f856d7fda2b68cabc86d6a4df/src/diffusers/pipelines/stable_diffusion/pipeline_onnx_stable_diffusion_inpaint.py#L324) and [width](https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/blob/f0c81562a43c183f856d7fda2b68cabc86d6a4df/src/diffusers/pipelines/stable_diffusion/pipeline_onnx_stable_diffusion_inpaint.py#L325) defaults to 512.

Comment: Thank you, I just figured this out minutes ago and was about to edit, now I have a new problem, if I pass anything other than a square image I get an onnx error ```[ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Non-zero status code returned while running Concat node. Name:'Concat_3563' Status Message: concat.cc:157 onnxruntime::ConcatBase::PrepareForCompute Non concat axis dimensions must match: Axis 2 has mismatched dimensions of 15 and 16```  ------- for a 320*480 image